# Flutter Dio Is there a way to set a limit on the number of concurrent requests

Tags: flutter, networking, concurrency, dio

I use Dio for networking in Flutter.

I tried to find a way to set the maximum number of concurrent requests.
I looked to BaseOptions and RequestOptions, but it seems there's no option.

How can I set that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no option related to limit of concurrent requests.

But I have a one idea to implement concurrent request limit by using 'QueuedInterceptor' .
(I am not sure that it works well)
https://github.com/flutterchina/dio#queuedinterceptor

I think that add a interceptor to dio instance and can control request and response count.

1. Add a 'QueuedInterceptor' interceptor at dio instance.
2. At 'onRequest' callback in 'QueuedInterceptor',
   increase current requested request counter.
   If requested request counter overs limit of request, reject a request with some error.
3. At 'onResponse' callback in 'QueuedInterceptor',
   decrease current requested request counter.